# Is there a way to work with the webbrowser module in Termux for Android?

Tags: python, python-3.x, termux

I have issues getting the `webbrowser` module in Python to open a website. It returns `False` as the output. I am a beginner and this is an example from the book "[Automate the Boring Stuff](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/)". Here's my error:

```
>>> import webbrowser
>>> webbrowser.open("http://example.com/")
False
```

Is there any way to go around this obstacle?

Comment: using `print(webbrowser.__file__)` you can get path to source code and you will see that it works only with some web browsers - but it uses code like `subprocess.run('chrome www.google.com')` to open url in browser so you can do the same with your web browser.

Answer (score 3):

Registering a browser might work:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.register("termux-open '%s'", None)
```

Comment: And after that just webbrowser.open("http://example.com/"),
just for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell it is not possible.

However, if you want to open a link on Termux for android you can use the following:

```
import os

def OpenLink(link):
    os.system("termux-open-url \""+link+"\"")
```

Also make sure the link starts with https, otherwise it might crash.

Answer (score 0):

To open url in Termux, simply type:

```
$ termux-open-url https://google.com
```

Answer (score -1):

Just Download PYDROID3 from play store and use the module and it will work..
Here is code that I tried..

import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('http://google.co.kr', new=2)